# Representation theory and particle physics

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics

Are there good books which explain clearly explain the connections between modern particle physics and representation theory of groups and lie algebras?

Answer (score 4):

1) [http://www.amazon.com/Lie-Algebras-Particle-Physics-Frontiers/dp/0738202339](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738202339)
This is a famous one for particle physics and Lie Algebras, and written by the master Georgi!

2) [http://www.amazon.com/Group-Theory-Physics-Wu-Ki-Tung/dp/9971966573](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9971966573)
this is an excellent read if you are trying to learn group theory as an undergraduate/beginner.

If you want any other books let me know, but Georgi's is definitely the best!